# How to compare jQuery variables values & get only greater than zero values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code where I have 3 different variables with different values and I want to compare all of them with 0 and get only those values which will be greater than 0 and Display them on screen in  with id="onam".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 10;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 7;
</script>
<label id="onam"></label>
```

with these values the result should be 10,7

Comment: _reply me asap_ Will you pay? Be courteous and wait for solution. Most important show your effort SO is not a code service we are here to help but you need to help yourself first.

Comment: so where is your jQuery code?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i will vote to  close simple comparison to 0 should not be a problem

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=comparison+with+3+different+values+in+jquery&oq=comparison+with+3+different+values+in+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57.996j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trying to write jquery or if you really mean vanilla javascript but here is for both options.

```
var a = 10;
var b = 0;
var c = 7;
var largerThan0 = [];

if(a > 0) {
     largerThan0.push(a);
}
if(b > 0) {
     largerThan0.push(b);
}
if(c > 0) {
     largerThan0.push(c);
}
$("#onam").text(largerThan0.join(" ")); //Jquery way
document.getElementById("onam").innerHTML = largerThan0.join(" "); //Javascript way
```

Comment: You might need to check your code again or paste it so i can see because i'm getting no problems by changing var a = 0; var b = 5; var c = 0;

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 10;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 7;

    if($a != 0){
         $("#onam").append($a + ',');
    }else if($b != 0){
         $("#onam").append($b + ',');
    }else if($c != 0){
         $("#onam").append($c);
    }
</script>
```